# Google Cloud Storage Client Library duplicate javax.transaction causing gradle build error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload images to Google Cloud Storage, using [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/#Java_Where_to_download_the_GCS_client_library)

I create a new project, and import dependencies in my Gradle like this:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.3.13'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
```

But when I run application, gradle had finished build with 1 error:

```
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 29.785 secs
Information:1 error
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I have worked out that the `javax.transaction.HeuristicCommitException.class` is in `transaction-api-1.1.jar`, which is a dependencies downloaded automatically when I import 2 above lines in my Gradle.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - your question came to me in a review queue to be improved.  I've tried to improve the formatting of links and code in the text (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details) and also added into the title the fact that the build error is what you want to solve.  Hopefully now an expert in using this library will see the question and help you to resolve it.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @JRichardSnape, I'm not very familiar with Gradle, but it looks like you're trying to download and build version 0.3.3 of appengine-gcs-client? That version is rather behind the times. Could you try 0.4.4 and see if it works better for you?`

Comment: Hi, I'm not the questioner, I just edited it. Not a gradle expert either, but your suggestion for solution sounds possible. Can you try it @donguyen

Comment: I tried the 0.4.4 release and got the same error :(